# Table Search segue not matching Table segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've implemented the 'Search Bar and Search Display Controller' on a tableview, and can see my results in the new table as I type. My issue is the cell I tap on in the search list doesn't lead to the same detail page as the cell in the table. I know the issue is with the indexPath.row in my segue, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

I guess my question comes down to, how do I get both tables to lead to the same detail page?

Below is my code:

```
#import "BuildingsViewController.h"
#import "BuildingsMapViewController.h"

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"buildingsCell";

@interface BuildingsViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *keys;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tempMutableArray;

@end

@implementation BuildingsViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveBuildings)];

    [self setTempMutableArray:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
                                                forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - TableView Setup

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [self.searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [self.buildingsArray count];
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        NSDictionary *tempDict = nil;
        NSString *tempString = nil;

        tempDict = [self.buildingsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        tempString = [tempDict objectForKey:@"buildingTitle"];

        [cell.textLabel setText:tempString];
    }
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Helper Methods

-(void)retrieveBuildings
{
    PFQuery *retrieveBuildings = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"buildingsList"];
    [retrieveBuildings orderByAscending:@"buildingTitle"];
    [retrieveBuildings findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            self.buildingsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = nil;

    [self.tempMutableArray removeAllObjects];
    for (NSDictionary *tempDict in self.buildingsArray) {
        NSString *tempString = nil;
        tempString = [tempDict objectForKey:@"buildingTitle"];
        [self.tempMutableArray addObject:tempString];
    }

    resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchText];
    self.searchResults = [self.tempMutableArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showMapDetail" sender: self];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showMapDetail"]) {
        BuildingsMapViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

        if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
            indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            destViewController.title = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            PFObject *object = [self.buildingsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            self.geoPoint = [object objectForKey:@"GeoPoint"];

        } else {
            indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NSDictionary *tempDict = nil;

            tempDict = [self.buildingsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"%@", tempDict);
            destViewController.title = [tempDict objectForKey:@"buildingTitle"];

            PFObject *object = [self.buildingsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            self.geoPoint = [object objectForKey:@"GeoPoint"];
        }

        destViewController.geoPoint = self.geoPoint;
        destViewController.annotationLat = self.geoPoint.latitude;
        destViewController.annotationLong = self.geoPoint.longitude;

    }

}

@end
```

UPDATED CODE (crash on segue):

```
#import "BuildingsViewController.h"
#import "BuildingsMapViewController.h"

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"buildingsCell";

@interface BuildingsViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *keys;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tempMutableArray;

@end

@implementation BuildingsViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveBuildings)];

    [self setTempMutableArray:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
                                                forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


#pragma mark - TableView Setup

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [self.searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [self.buildingsArray count];
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        NSDictionary *tempDict = nil;
        NSString *tempString = nil;

        tempDict = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        tempString = [tempDict objectForKey:@"buildingTitle"];
        cell.textLabel.text = tempString;


    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        NSDictionary *tempDict = nil;
        NSString *tempString = nil;

        tempDict = [self.buildingsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        tempString = [tempDict objectForKey:@"buildingTitle"];

        [cell.textLabel setText:tempString];
    }
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Helper Methods

-(void)retrieveBuildings
{
    PFQuery *retrieveBuildings = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"buildingsList"];
    [retrieveBuildings setLimit:300];
    [retrieveBuildings orderByAscending:@"buildingTitle"];
    [retrieveBuildings findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            self.buildingsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = nil;

    [self.tempMutableArray removeAllObjects];
    for (NSDictionary *tempDict in self.buildingsArray) {
        NSString *tempString = nil;
        tempString = [tempDict objectForKey:@"buildingTitle"];
        [self.tempMutableArray addObject:tempString];
    }

    resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"buildingTitle contains[cd] %@", searchText];
    self.searchResults = [self.buildingsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showMapDetail" sender: self];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showMapDetail"]) {
        BuildingsMapViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

        if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
            indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            destViewController.title = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            PFObject *object = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            self.geoPoint = [object objectForKey:@"GeoPoint"];

        } else {
            indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NSDictionary *tempDict = nil;

            tempDict = [self.buildingsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"%@", tempDict);
            destViewController.title = [tempDict objectForKey:@"buildingTitle"];

            PFObject *object = [self.buildingsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            self.geoPoint = [object objectForKey:@"GeoPoint"];
        }

        destViewController.geoPoint = self.geoPoint;
        destViewController.annotationLat = self.geoPoint.latitude;
        destViewController.annotationLong = self.geoPoint.longitude;

    }

}

@end
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Do you have a segue setup from the cell in the main table view? What controller does it go to?

Comment: I've always maintained a BOOL that I set to YES when searching, and check that when tapping a row to know what data source to use.

Comment: Check this tutorial, http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/

Comment: @Kaiusee That's the tutorial I was following. I'm pulling data from Parse, so it's a little different.
at rdelmar I do have a segue with the identifier 'showMapDetail.' It leads to a view controller with a Map view, where I have the user location and corresponding pin.
at Stonz2I'm not sure how to use a BOOL here.

Comment: Your problem is not at all clear. If the segue from the main table goes to the same controller as the segue called "showMapDetail", which you perform from the search table, then you will go to the same detail controller. If they're different, then they won't. Do you have two different detail view controllers in your storyboard?

Comment: @rdelmar Tapping on any cell should lead you to one view controller with a map view; the only difference is the annotation that's loaded. Here's an example of the issue. Say the original table has cells A, B, C. If I tap on C, the map view loads the annotation in position 2 of an array, which is what I want. However, if I use the search to find C, C will be the only cell in the search list, giving it the position 0. Tapping on C now loads positions 0 of the original list (in this case, A).

Comment: The problem is the way you create the searchResults array. Instead of populating that array with strings, you should populate it with PFObjects like you do for buildingsArray. Then in prepareForSegue, instead of using PFObject *object = [self.buildingsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];, you'll be able to use PFObject *object = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: @rdelmar I've updated the code in my answer to use objects instead of the string array; however, it crashes on the segue. The error I get is '[PFObject copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d8d5a0.'

Comment: You should add an exception breakpoint to see what line causes that error

Comment: Good advice, I found the line. It's the "destViewController.title = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];" How would I set the title then for the detail page?